# Json String posting in Slack without formating

Tags: javascript, json, axios, slack

I am trying to post test result on Slack. Posting the message works but it is posted as a whole json string.

Here is my code:

```
testITArray = ["Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3r"];
        testITStatusArray = [":white_check_mark:", ":x:", ":x:"];

        var edited = "{";
        for (var i = 0; i < testITArray.length; i++) {
            edited +=
                '"type": "context","elements": [{"type": "mrkdwn","text": "' +
                testITArray[i] +
                '"},{"type": "mrkdwn","text": " ' +
                testITStatusArray[i] +
                ' "}],';
        }
        edited = edited.slice(0, -1);
        edited += "}";

        var asJSON = JSON.stringify(edited);
        axios.post("https://hooks.slack.com/XXXX",
            {
                text: `${asJSON}`,
            }
        );

Tried this option also
         // axios.post("https://hooks.slack.com/XXXX",asJSON,{
         //headers: {
           //  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
           //}
}
            
        );
```

Here is my output.

Actual result:

[image: See Actual Result]

Expected result:

[image: See Expected Result]

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few things wrong with this code:

1. You are composing a json string so you don't need to use `JSON.stringify`.
2. Your json string contains the same keys over and over so they will be overwritten by the last one.
3. It is unclear what the shape of the array should be.
4. It is not a best practice to compose a json string in JS because it can easily lead to an error.

I tried to guess the shape of the json that you need. Let me know if it is what you were looking for:

```js
const yourResult = '{"type": "context","elements": [{"type": "mrkdwn","text": "Test 1"},{"type": "mrkdwn","text": " :white_check_mark: "}],"type": "context","elements": [{"type": "mrkdwn","text": "Test 2"},{"type": "mrkdwn","text": " :x: "}],"type": "context","elements": [{"type": "mrkdwn","text": "Test 3r"},{"type": "mrkdwn","text": " :x: "}]}'


console.log('your string', yourResult)
console.log('parsed result', JSON.parse(yourResult))


const testITArray = ["Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3r"];
const testITStatusArray = [":white_check_mark:", ":x:", ":x:"];

const resultArray = testITArray.map((t, i) => {
  return {
    type: "context",
    elements: [t, testITStatusArray[i]].map(text => ({
      type: 'mrkdwn',
      text
    }))
  }
})

const resultSingleObject = testITArray.flatMap((t, i) => [t, testITStatusArray[i]])
  .reduce((res, text) => ({
    ...res,
    elements: [...res.elements, {
      type: 'mrkdwn',
      text
    }]
  }), {
    type: 'context',
    elements: []
  })


console.log('array', resultArray)
console.log('array json', JSON.stringify(resultArray))
console.log('object', resultSingleObject)
console.log('object json', JSON.stringify(resultSingleObject))
```

Comment: Array Json string is valid for me. but slack access within                                                           
 ```{ blocks : [ resultArray ] }```                                                                                               I tried following code but its not sending on slack                    
                   ```axios.post(
   "https://hooks.slack.com/XXX",
   { blocks: [`${JSON.stringify(resultArray)}`] }
  );```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @R4ncid, here is my solution. I have added JSON array within block string.

```js
const json = "{ blocks: " + `${JSON.stringify(resultArray)}` + " }";
const res = axios.post(
        "https://hooks.slack.com/XXX",
        `${json}`
    );
```